# Sending json through api post request

Tags: c#, json, axios

I'm currently struggling to send a JSON via post request into my controller to use it further by calling a stored procedure.

Here is the post request using axios:

```
async returnJSON(model) {
      this.info = await axios.post(
          "https://localhost:44349/api/items/AddItem/",model)
        .then((response) => response.data);
```

Here is the structure of model:

```
{
  "arrayAutori": [
    {
      "dinUniversitate": true,
      "creatorType": 4,
      "creatorID": 3
    }
  ],
  "itemID": "",
  "itemTypeID": 6,      
  "drepturiDeAutor": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 15
  },
  "isbn": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 25
  },
  "limba": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 7
  },
  "numarPagini": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 43
  },
  "data": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 6
  },
  "editura": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 23
  },
  "editie": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 42
  },
  "volum": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 19
  },
  "numarColectie": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 41
  },
  "titlu": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 1
  }
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
 public string AddItem( JObject jsonString)
        {
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec zotero.PublicationsMerge " + jsonString);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return "1";
        }
```

I can not make a model class to use it, because that JSON may vary depending on the publications.
Also, when I'm debugging this controller, jsonString looks like this:

```
{{
  "arrayAutori": [
    {
      "dinUniversitate": true,
      "creatorType": 4,
      "creatorID": 3
    }
  ],
  "itemID": "",
  "itemTypeID": 6,
  "drepturiDeAutor": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 15
  },
  "isbn": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 25
  },
  "limba": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 7
  },
  "numarPagini": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 43
  },
  "data": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 6
  },
  "editura": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 23
  },
  "editie": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 42
  },
  "volum": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 19
  },
  "numarColectie": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 41
  },
  "titlu": {
    "valueID": "",
    "fieldID": 1
  }
}}
```

I don't know why, but it adds another pair of {}. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like there's a visual bug that adds another pair of curly brackets in debugging mode and it's caused by JObject. Nothing serious

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).